# Angular 4 template binding for glyph icons

Tags: angular, fonts, angular2-template, iconic

I'm trying to use open iconic icons but once I tried to dynamically set the icon name to data-glyph attributs it crash
The error is:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'glyph' since it isn't a known property of 'span'. ("
<span class="oi" [ERROR ->]data-glyph="{{value}}" title="icon name" aria-hidden="true"></span>
"): ng:///AppModule/ImageButtonComponent.html@1:17
```

Template part:

```
<span class="oi" data-glyph="{{value}}" title="icon name" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Comment: How did you include the icons?

Comment: is this some kind of module of `glyphicons` you can make use of glypohicons directly ?

Comment: It's open iconic https://useiconic.com/open I just add the css file under HTML header tag

Comment: Can you rename your question to something more broad? Your question is about custom attributes in common, not only about glyph icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this this:

```
<span [attr.data-glyph]="value"></span>
```

Plunkr example is available [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/oCHuCu5LYptftXXkOfVb?p=preview).